# Micronaut config not issuing a JWT refresh token

Tags: java, jwt, micronaut

I have the following config in my `application.yml`. According to the specs this should issue a refresh token besides the access token in the `JWT` response, but I get just the access token and not the refresh one.

Am I missing something?

```
token:
  jwt:
    signatures:
      secret:
        generator:
          refresh-token:
            secret: "${JWT_GENERATOR_SIGNATURE_SECRET:pleaseChangeThisSecretForANewOne}"  
          secret: "${JWT_GENERATOR_SIGNATURE_SECRET:pleaseChangeThisSecretForANewOne}"
```

Comment: May be you have wrong yaml path to some micronaut parameters...
This is from my prod setup of jwt but in *.properties format

`micronaut.security.authentication=bearer
micronaut.security.token.jwt.signatures.secret.generator.secret="${JWT_GENERATOR_SIGNATURE_SECRET\:unit_testing_jwt_generator_secret}"
micronaut.security.token.jwt.generator.refresh-token.secret="${JWT_GENERATOR_REFRESH_SECRET\:unit_testing_jwt_refresh_secret}"`

And refresh token should appear at least on login endpoint (and on refresh endpoint path from variable `micronaut.security.endpoints.oauth.path`).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing an implementation of `RefreshTokenPersistence`.

I'd suggest you to read this section of micronaut's security docs: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-security/latest/guide/#refresh

Here is a very very naive implementation of the persistence unit. Please do not forget to add `@Singleton` to your implementation. I was missing exactly that, which was the reason why micronaut did not generate a refresh token at first in my own project.

```
import io.micronaut.security.authentication.UserDetails;
import io.micronaut.security.token.event.RefreshTokenGeneratedEvent;
import io.micronaut.security.token.refresh.RefreshTokenPersistence;
import io.reactivex.BackpressureStrategy;
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;

import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Singleton
public class MyRefreshTokenPersistence implements RefreshTokenPersistence {

    private final Map<String, UserDetails> storage = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void persistToken(RefreshTokenGeneratedEvent event) {
        storage.put(event.getRefreshToken(), event.getUserDetails());
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher<UserDetails> getUserDetails(String refreshToken) {
        return Flowable.create(emitter -> {
            final UserDetails userDetails = storage.get(refreshToken);
            if ( userDetails != null ) {
                emitter.onNext(userDetails);
                emitter.onComplete();
            } else {
                emitter.onError(new IllegalArgumentException("refresh token unknown"));
            }
        }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
    }
}
```

Comment: Issue and persist refresh token are completely different processes.

Comment: @Leandro Lima No, you are not right. Assuming authentication mode is "bearer". See: `AccessRefreshTokenLoginHandler line 54 call to generate > DefaultAccessRefreshTokenGenerator line 95 call to generateRefreshToken > same class line 107`: `if (beanContext.containsBean(RefreshTokenPersistence.class)) { ...`. There the presence of the RefreshTokenPersistence will be checked.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue with Micronaut v3.1.4. It needs a class that implements RefreshTokenPersistence. This worked for me.

```
import io.micronaut.security.authentication.Authentication;
import io.micronaut.security.token.event.RefreshTokenGeneratedEvent;
import io.micronaut.security.token.refresh.RefreshTokenPersistence;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;

@Singleton
public class CustomRefreshTokenPersistence implements RefreshTokenPersistence {

    @Override
    public void persistToken(final RefreshTokenGeneratedEvent event) {
   
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher<Authentication> getAuthentication(final String refreshToken) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel your application.yml configurations are looking a little out of order to me. As the documents suggest it should have been something similar to as below.

```
micronaut:
  security:
    authentication: bearer
    token:
      jwt:
        signatures:
          secret:
            generator:
              secret: '"${JWT_GENERATOR_SIGNATURE_SECRET:pleaseChangeThisSecretForANewOne}"'
        generator:
          refresh-token:
            secret: '"${JWT_GENERATOR_SIGNATURE_SECRET:pleaseChangeThisSecretForANewOne}"'
```

***Link to the micronuat document:*** https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-security-jwt-gradle-groovy.html